# A sequence that changes sign finally at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

I want to make a sequence $a_n$ that changes its sign at infinity.

What I'm try to make is this: $a_n$ of negative number or zero $\to$  it's limit is some positive $\epsilon$ right next to zero.

$\qquad a_n \le 0$    (for all n  $\in Z^+$)

$\qquad \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = \epsilon $, where $\epsilon\gt 0$.

Is this sequence possible?

Could you find an explicit function?
$\,\,$  Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is impossible. Try considering the epsilon-delta definition of a limit.

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: Not possible, sorry.  $0$ is an upper bound for your entire sequence so $\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n≤0$.

Comment: It's possible if you're willing to be flexible with the definition of $=$. E.g. if you define the divergent series $1+2+3+\cdots$ to be "equal" to $\zeta(-1)$ then $1+2+3+\cdots+n=\tfrac12n(n+1)>0$ but $\zeta(-1)=-\tfrac{1}{12}.$ But this is a divergent series in the usual sense.

Comment: If there is an $L$ such that $a_n\le L$ for all $n$, then you can conclude that the limit (if it exists!) satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \le L$ as well. So that rules out an example like the one you ask for. The thing to be aware of, is that if you try with _strict_ inequalities, i.e. you require that $a_n<L$ for all $n$, then you cannot conclude that the limit is also _strictly_ less than $L$ (if it exists).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Suppose otherwise. Then, there is some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that$$n\geqslant N\implies\lvert a_n-\varepsilon\rvert<\varepsilon\iff0<a_n<2\varepsilon.$$But this is impossible, since you are assuming that you always have $a_n\leqslant0$.

Answer (score 3):

Such a sequence doesn't exist. Note that if $a_n \le 0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N_0$, then $0$ is an upper bound of the sequence, so in particular

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n\le\sup_{n\in\Bbb N_0} a_n \le 0.$$